# How to create a new event for my own custom control?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a class which inherit from Panel, and below are some member in this class

```
Public ItemName As String
Public Quantity As Integer
Public Price As Decimal
Public DiscountAmount As Decimal
```

How can I create a event when Quantity or DiscountAmount changed then run a function?

I try to write in this way but I get error:-

```
Private Sub info_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Quantity.Changed, DiscountAmount.Changed
    myFunction()
End Sub
```

> Error:
>   Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the
>   containing type or one of its base types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the events in user control and then consume those. See below code. I have created a user control `UserControl1`. This control raises events when `Price` or `DiscountAmount` is changed. The usercontrol is then used in Form1. You can use the same approach to change the `Quantity`.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents userCntrl As New UserControl1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ChangeValues()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeValues()
        userCntrl.Price = 100
        userCntrl.DiscountAmount = 12
    End Sub

    Private Sub userCntrl_Price_Changed(newValue As Decimal) Handles userCntrl.Price_Changed, userCntrl.DiscountAmount_Changed
        MessageBox.Show("New value = " & newValue.ToString)
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class UserControl1
    Public Event Price_Changed(ByVal newValue As Decimal)
    Public Event DiscountAmount_Changed(ByVal newValue As Decimal)

    Public ItemName As String
    Public Quantity As Integer

    Private Price_ As Decimal
    Public Property Price() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Price_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            If value <> Price_ Then
                RaiseEvent Price_Changed(value)
            End If
            Price_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private DiscountAmount_ As Decimal
    Public Property DiscountAmount() As Decimal
        Get
            Return DiscountAmount_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            If value <> DiscountAmount_ Then
                RaiseEvent DiscountAmount_Changed(value)
            End If
            DiscountAmount_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```